# Does Apple set UIView tags?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uitableview

I want to set the `tag` of a `UITableViewCell` that I, personally, create, with `initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier:` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, to `0` or `1` to indicate whether I should position its subviews to the left or right. Is it safe to do this, or will Apple mess with the value of this cell's tag? I know I could use a separate cell identifier for each type of cell, but both cells are pretty much the same, besides positioning of subviews and some colors. (I'm recreating the native Messages app with the chat bubbles.)

Answer (score 3):

While you can certainly use tags, I'd definitely suggest to be more explicit. You will do yourself a favor when you look at your code a few months from now. I'd create a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass that has a `contentAlignment` property that you can explicitly set to `left` or `right`. It will be much more readable that (ab)using the cell's tag.

Something like this:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyTableViewCellContentAlignment) {
    MyTableViewCellContentAlignmentLeft,
    MyTableViewCellContentAlignmentRight
};

@interface MyTableViewCell : UITableViewCell

@property (assign, nonatomic) enum MyTableViewCellContentAlignment contentAlignment;

@end
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Great answer, I would use exactly this solution.

Comment: Yeah, do that. Much better than my crappy answer below.

Answer (score 1):

It's okay, but a better place to set the tag would be the `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method of the UITableViewDelegate. According to the docs:

> A table view sends this message to its delegate just before it uses cell to draw a row, thereby permitting the delegate to customize the cell object before it is displayed. This method gives the delegate a chance to override state-based properties set earlier by the table view, such as selection and background color. After the delegate returns, the table view sets only the alpha and frame properties, and then only when animating rows as they slide in or out.

Answer (score 1):

It is absolutely safe to set a `UITableViewCell`'s (or any `UIView`'s) tag to whatever value you want.  No one (including Apple) will mess with this tag's value outside the control of your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's OK to give `UITableViewCell` a `tag`. Interface Builder lets you do it. Still, feeling shaky about doing so is understandable. Normally, you'd give a tag to a view that you're explicitly adding to another view via `addSubview:`. But, think about it. If Apple messed with the values of any of the tags of the views within your view controller's `view`, then that could break the functionality of something like `[self.view viewWithTag:TEXT_FIELD_TAG]`. So, I doubt they would. I have heard once that Apple reserves the tag integers <= 10, and therefore, you should use integers > 10 for tag values, but I don't see how that could be true.